# Send array into data by POST method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, post

I'm calling an api rest in codeigniter, the problem it's when i send the array arrive to the server at this way:

```
[{"PMcolor":"Azul tostado","PMpartes":"Un poquito de las orjeas y un bigote a lo Dali, quizas le alegre la cara","PMcosteTotal":"445"}]:
```

My object is:

```
myobject = {PMcolor: "Azul tostado", PMpartes: "Un poquito de las orjeas y un bigote a lo Dali, quizas le alegre la cara", PMcosteTotal: "445" };
```

and i triyed this methods POST:

1)

```
$scope.datosEnviar = [];
    $scope.datosEnviar.push(myobject);

  var config={ //este funciona, NO TOCAR, esto es en cuanto a post
    method:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/APIREST/controllersencillo/", 
    params: {tabla : "PintaMonas"} 
    ,data:  $scope.datosEnviar,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }
```

2)

```
var config={ //este funciona, NO TOCAR, esto es en cuanto a post
    method:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/APIREST/controllersencillo/", 
    params: {tabla : "PintaMonas"} //with id update, whitout id insert
    ,data:  myobject,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }
```

Comment: looks like it's doing exactly what you're telling it to. you're pushing your object into an array, and it's arriving as an array with one element, your object. what would you like for it to look like when it arrives?

Comment: so the API expects a JS object...?

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: the api expects a JS object, correct, the method 1 and 2 doesn't send the object, only arrive the array that i showed. ¿ **why** ? or ¿ **how** must send the data?

Comment: and `[{"PMcolor":"Azul tostado","PMpartes":"Un poquito de las orjeas y un bigote a lo Dali, quizas le alegre la cara","PMcosteTotal":"445"}`  **]:**    isn't a complet array. it's only a field with a empty value

Comment: PS: if i send by the method 2, show this: `{"PMcolor":"Azul tostado","PMpartes":"Un poquito de las orjeas y un bigote a lo Dali, quizas le alegre la cara","PMcosteTotal":"445"}:""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
,data: 'PMcolor='+myobject.PMcolor+"&PMpartes="+myobject.PMpartes+"&PMcosteTotal="+myobject.PMcosteTotal,
```

isn't an array... but work

Answer (score 0):

i fond a partial solution, but i can't send an array, they send the array with string format, now i must know how send the array in array format.

```
$scope.datosEnviar = [myobject];
    /*$scope.datosEnviar.push(myobject.PMcolor);
    $scope.datosEnviar.push(myobject.PMpartes);
    $scope.datosEnviar.push(myobject.PMcosteTotal);*/

  var config={ //este funciona, NO TOCAR, esto es en cuanto a post
    method:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/APIREST/controllersencillo/", //id: JSON.stringify(ids) //{PMcolor: "Azul tostado", PMpartes: "Un poquito de las orjeas y un bigote a lo Dali", PMcosteTotal: "445" }
    params: {tabla : "PintaMonas"/*, data: JSON.stringify($scope.datosEnviar)*/} //sin id es insert, con id es update
    ,data: 'PMcolor='+ JSON.stringify($scope.datosEnviar),//myobject.PMcolor+", PMpartes="+myobject.PMpartes+", PMcosteTotal="+myobject.PMcosteTotal,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }
```

now send the next array **[PMcolor] => [{"PMcolor":"Azul tostado","PMpartes":"Un poquito de las orjeas y un bigote a lo Dali, quizas le alegre la cara","PMcosteTotal":"445"}]** but the data it's with string format.